# Adding custom Application class to production application

Tags: android

I want to add custom Application instance to my app which is on google play already. I know that i cannot change name or package of Activities in production apps. But i didn't found any information about Application class. Is it possible to add custom Application instance to production app without breaking anything (auto update etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. its possible.

the package name is the unique name Identifier for the app. there is no relation between package name and Application class. All you have to do for adding Application class is add `<application>` tag in the manifest file :

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

And then create the application class and extend `Application`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```